# Is it possible to use Xamarin Forms Controls in a Uno project?

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, cross-platform, xamarin.mac, uno-platform

I am currently developing a cross-platform (Windows and Mac) app using Uno and WinUI 3. I need to implement a `WebView` in my project, but I'm having some trouble.

On Windows I can use the new `WebView2` from WinUI without any problem, but being not supported by Uno I can't use it on Mac. On Mac I think I can't even use the `WebView1` because it is not supported anymore in WinUI 3 (and so in Uno.WinUI, or am I wrong?).

So I thought to use the Xamarin.Forms `WebView` on Mac, but I don't know how to implement it. I thought to add a new project to the solution with just the `WebView` and call it from the Uno.Mac project, but it doesn't work.

May you give me any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, it seems impossible to achieve that. The Uno project based on UWP, and `using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;` to design the user interface. Unless you can reference `Xamarin.Forms` package inside it.

Comment: I have just created a PR that fixes the `WebView` control on macOS. It should be merged soon, so the newest preview packages should support it properly https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/pull/5041

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use Uno Platform controls in Xamarin.Forms app (see [docs](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/howto-use-uno-in-xamarin-forms.html)). The other way may also be possible as there [was a way](https://montemagno.com/embedding-xamarinforms-into-a-xamarin-native-app/) to embed a Xamarin.Forms control in a native app, and Uno allows embedding native controls (see [docs](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/native-views.html)).

However, a more efficient solution would be to use the built-in `WebView` control that Uno Platform provides (unless it is missing some functionality you require - in which case please raise an issue on GitHub :-) ).

Alternatively, you could also directly embed the native macOS `WKWebView` (using the steps linked to above) and work with it directly.

Comment: Have you tried yourself to use Xamarin.Forms controls inside a Uno Platform application for various targets? Or any examples you may have? I'm currently experimenting with those possibilities so that could be really handy.

Comment: Unfortunately not personally, but if you join Uno Platform on Discord, you can ask the team almost real-time :-) https://platform.uno/blog/uno-platform-online-community-move-to-stackoverflow-and-discord/

Comment: I have joined the discord channel and asked the question, hopefully some answers will come out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin.Forms controls cannot be used individually in an Uno app, in the same way those cannot be used in a Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android "classic" app.

You can, however, use the the Xamarin.Forms embedding technique described [in this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-forms). The base of the technique is to create a `ContentPage`, then add it as a native control.

Uno Platform supports adding native controls directly in the Visual Tree by assigning the native view to the `Content` property of a `ContentControl` using code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add Xamarin content into uno and vice versa.

Just try this :

```
public partial class XamarinContent : ContentControl
    {

        View _element;
        public View Element
        {
            get => _element;
            set
            {
                _element = value;

#if __ANDROID__
                var renderer = RendererFactory.GetRenderer(value);
                this.Content = renderer.View;
                this.SizeChanged += (s, a) => {
                    _element.Layout(new Rect(0, 0, a.NewSize.Width, a.NewSize.Height));
                };
#else
                var converter = new ViewToRendererConverter();
                var frameworkElement = converter.Convert(value, null, null, null);
                this.Content = frameworkElement;
               // this.SetValue(ContentControl.ContentProperty, frameworkElement) ;
#endif
            }
        }
    }
```

and to convert from uno into Xamarin forms

```
   [ContentProperty("Element")]
    public class UnoContent : Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty ContentProperty
            = BindableProperty.Create("Element", typeof(Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement), typeof(View), null);

        public Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement Element
        {
            get { return (Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); base.ControlTemplate = new Xamarin.Forms.ControlTemplate(() => value.ToView()); }
        }

        
    }
```